# How to use "Like" operator in sqlAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi I am a new member in stackoverflow. I am currently using sqlAlchemy in flask. Trying to get the matched categories of string provided with the search url. The code of search url is given below:

```
@productapi.route("/search/category", methods=["GET"])
def search_category():
    category_param_value = request.args.get('querystr', None)
    print(category_param_value)
    if category_param_value is None:
        return jsonify(message='Which category you want to search????'), 400
    try:
        category = Category.query.filter_by(
            title=Category.title.like("category_param_value %"))
    except SQLAlchemyError as err:
        return jsonify(message='Category not found.'), 400
    category_list = category_schema.dumps(category)
    return category_list.data, 200
```

I tried with httpie with following url: http get http://192.168.1.98:5000/api/v1/search/category?querystr="test"

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: character varying = boolean
```

Hoping for a positive response. Thank You.

Comment: Interpolating variables to strings is only available in Python 3.6 and up, and the syntax would be `f"{category_param_value}%"`. Be careful though; interpolating variables to raw SQL strings, HTML etc. is **dangerous**. In this case you're not using raw SQL, so you're ok.

Answer (score 17):

You are not using the correct syntax. Also you should format the string you are passing to `like`.

Change this line:

```
category = Category.query.filter_by(title=Category.title.like("category_param_value %"))
```

to this:

```
category = Category.query.filter(Category.title.like(category_param_value + "%")).all()
```

Comment: Thank u. Its working fine now. I made mistake of using % with argument.